# wagtailmenus - iterating submenu items

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm getting started with wagtail, (and Django), and using wagtailmenus.

I'm having trouble getting the submenu object that I (presumably) iterate to build submenus where required.

> main_menu.html

```
{% for item in menu_items %}
    <li class="dropdown nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link href="{{ item.href }}">{{ item.text }}</a>
        {% if item.has_children_in_menu %}
            {% sub_menu item %}
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

This code renders the top level items fine, and recognises when the submenu is required, and references the correct template.

> sub_menu.html

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <a href="{{ item.href }}" class="dropdown-item">
       {{ item }}
  </a>
</div>
```

However, `item` is the previous item - so I just get the top level item repeated, once.

As far as I can figure out, I need to get a iterable object of the sub menu, and build it in the same way as the top level menu. Something like,

> pseudo_sub_menu.html

```
{% for sub_item in item %}
      <a href="{{ sub_item.href }}" class="dropdown-item">
           {{ sub_item.text }}
      </a>
{% endfor %}
```

But that returns

> 'MainMenuItem' object is not iterable

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out with the Django Debug Toolbar.

```
main_menu.html

                    {% if item.has_children_in_menu %}
                        {% sub_menu item %}
                    {% endif %}

sub_menu.html

                    {% for item in menu_items %}
                        <a href="{{ item.href }}" class="dropdown-item">
                            {{ item.text }}
                        </a>
                    {% endfor %}
```